# cannot connect to fresh installed gitlab 7.0 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: gitlab, centos6, ssh-keys, openssh

When i try to connect with ssh to the fresh installed gitlab he ask for a password. the http is working aswel the webinterface.

I have already added the rsa key to gitlab but it looks like the openssh server not use the gitlab authorized_keys file.

Gitlab version 7.0

installed fresh CentOS 6.5 and followed this commands:

```
wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/centos-6.5/gitlab-7.0.0_omnibus-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install openssh-server
sudo yum install postfix # Select 'Internet Site', using sendmail or exim is also OK
sudo rpm -i gitlab-7.0.0_omnibus-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

sudo -e /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

(added my hostname)

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo lokkit -s http -s ssh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on GitLab 7 omnibus on CentOS 6.5: after a fresh install, when I `git push git@....` it was asking for a password. I fixed it by changing the permissions on `.ssh` folder and `.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
yum install policycoreutils-python -y
chmod 700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/
chmod 600 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh"
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"
restorecon -R -v /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/
```

You will probably need `policycoreutils-python` package to run `semanage`. Install it with `yum` if needed !